# Design related to collection view

Tags: ios

I have to create 3x3 to 15x15 collection view . I have multiple buttons. when I click third button the design would be 3 x 3 , when I click fourth button the design will be 4 x4 unto 15 button click design will be 15 x 15.how to achieve this design.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello Nitesh and welcome to Stack Overflow, please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: simple show what you have tried its easy to answer

Comment: @Nitesh Baranwal - here I attached the sample project based on your ?, try this : https://www.sendspace.com/file/lgtixe